# how to upload local image to s3 and use its link to view the image

Tags: python, boto3

I want to upload local images to s3 and view those images using the links instead of downloading them currently the images I am uploading are getting downloaded when I open there links in the browser. I have also added the content type to image/png in AWS metadata but then also it is getting downloaded currently I am using this function in python to upload the images

`uploaded = upload_to_aws('file.png', 's3','file.png')`

function

```
def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
    s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
    print("Upload Successful")
    return True
```

Comment: how is the func `uplodad` defined?

Comment: sorry i forgot that

Comment: When you upload the files, why do you not also dynamically generate an html file and upload that with all the links to the images?

Comment: can you send a demo

Answer (score 0):

Per the boto3 docs on [`S3.upload_file`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file), it looks like you would have to pass `ExtraArgs` as a `dict` parameter when calling the `upload_file()` method.

Note also, that the allowed upload args are documented [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer.ALLOWED_UPLOAD_ARGS).

For example:

```
s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file, 
               ExtraArgs=dict(ContentType='image/png'))
```